# Middle click tab opening stopped working in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Today I booted up my PC, opened Firefox, and went through my usual habit of going to some pages, middle clicking every interesting new link to open it in a new tab, and then casually working my way through them. Today however I've noticed that this doesn't work any more.

**What DOES work:**

- Middle clicking on a link in my bookmarks bar opens it in a new page
- Middle click scrolling
- Right click -> Open in new tab

**What DOESN'T work:**

- Middle clicking any link on any web page to open it in a new tab
- CTRL + clicking on a link to open it in a new tab

I haven't installed any new add-ons or removed anything - the function just... disappeared. I checked the value of `browser.tabs.opentabfor.middleclick` in `about:config` and it's set to true.

Has anyone happened to have had the same problem, and if so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue! Here's [a solution to the problem](https://plus.google.com/106764458835637721222/posts/haLKEu3Qm39):

> You probably have Tab Mix Plus and Greasemonkey extensions, right?
>   Well, a few hours ago Greasemonkey updated their extension and there
>   seems to be a conflict between new GM and TMP. Just downgrade your GM
>   to [the previous version](https://arantius.com/misc/gm-nightly/arch/greasemonkey-2011.08.20.nightly.xpi) and everything will go back to normal.

The [latest version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/versions/) of Greasemonkey also has a work-around for the issue.

Comment: Good answer, but really you need to post it *here* rather than making people click one more time than they need to.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know it matters :). Thanks.

Comment: That solved it! I just disabled TabMixPlus as I never recall even USING the functions they supply, so it all works again now :) Thanks!

Comment: enough to get the answer *and* an upvote. ;)

Comment: Too bad I can't middle click that link to fix it...