# Ctrl+Left Click on a link does not open a new tab in Firefox (with Tab Mix Plus)

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Middle click tab opening stopped working in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/332782/middle-click-tab-opening-stopped-working-in-firefox)

My Firefox is up-to-date and equipped with Tab Mix Plus plugin. Somehow, when I am holding the left CTRL on my keyboard and left-click on a link, no tabs are created. After disabling the Tab Mix Plus plugin, the problem is resolved. I have pored over the options of the plugin and can't find anything relevant.

I must have missed something. Please help. :)

Comment: It's right! Now GM's newest version 0.9.11 resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Note : if you click with the scroll wheel on an link it will be opened on a new tab

With tabmix + it's always available. It's not the solution for your problem, but an alternative way to proceded